# WCF class implementing two operation contracts in different service contracts with same name

Tags: c#, wcf, multiple-inheritance, servicecontract, operationcontract

I have declared two service contracts as follows:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IContract1
{
    [OperationContract]
    double Add(int ip);
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IContract2
{
    [OperationContract]
    double Add(double ip);
}
```

I have a class which implements these two contracts. I have created two endpoints for both contracts. But I'm not able to access the service from client code.
It displays a big error when I try to update the service reference as:

> Metadata contains an error that cannot be resolved.... There was no endpoint listening at ... , etc.

I know that you can't have two `OperationContract`s with the same name but is it possible to have two operation contracts in different service contracts with same name but different signature?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If one service implements both contracts then you should give unique names to your operation contracts.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IContract1
{
    [OperationContract(Name="AddInt")]
    double Add(int ip);
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IContract2
{
    [OperationContract(Name="AddDouble")]
    double Add(double ip);
}
```

Comment: how shall I consume the method then?
It just shows only one method in client code.

Comment: Got that, I will create two clients corresponding to two service contracts. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IContract1
{
    [OperationContract(Name = "Add1")]
    double Add(int ip);
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IContract2
{
    [OperationContract(Name = "Add2")]
    double Add(double ip);
}
```